# Importing Sass Map

Tags: drupal, sass

I found a nice way of setting up my typography online that uses Sass Maps. It recommends setting up my breakpoints this way.

```
 $breakpoints: (
   bp1: value,
   bp2: value,
   etc.
 );
```

I can't seem to import them into a layout stylesheet though. I tried importing my mixins and functions but they still don't seem to work. It seems like it is not importing the map.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Got it working but I don't think I am using Globbing.
     @import "../variables/grid";
     @import "../helpers/mixins";

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Turns out the whole problem was due to Sass Globbing. 1.1.1 doesn't seem to get along with the Omega 4 Drupal theme. Had to downgrade it to 1.1.0 in my Gemfile and run Bundle. Seems to work great now!